# Use Google Maps marker coordinates as form input

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, bootstrap-4

From the below javascript function, I get a javascript variable **marker** with coordinates when the user clicks a position on the map.

```
var marker;
function placeMarker(location) {
  if ( marker ) {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

**Question**
How can these coordinates be used as form input?

```
<form method="POST" action="/authors" target="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: It is hard to answer you without more information about the context. You can imagine to loop on your markers, retrieve their position property and you these properties as values to your input tag within your form. Is that the kind of things you would like to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is take the `location` variable and assign it to your form input like this:

First, add a hidden input field

```
<form method="POST" action="/authors" target="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="location" name="location" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

Second, make sure the location variable gets added to your input

```
var marker;
function placeMarker(location) {
  if ( marker ) {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  } else {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
  }

  $("#location").val(location);

}
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Now, whenever `placeMarker(location)` gets called it will update the input with the id of "location" and its value is the output of `location`.

Comment: Superb! A nice simple solution. This may be a trivial question, but I could not find the answer on here, and I'm not proficient at Javascript. Thanks again!

Comment: I changed your solution slightly as to store the coordinates separately by using the location variable's properties:       `$("#latitude").val(location.lat());`
`$("#longitude").val(location.lng());`

Comment: That's a great idea too!